# When should a function be inline or not?

Tags: c++, inline, header-files

Say I have the following class declared in a header file, with a friend function `swap`:

```
// header.h
class myClass
{
    friend void swap(myClass &, myClass &);

public:
    myClass(int ii = 0) : i(ii) {}

private:
    int i;
};
```

Now I want to define `swap`. If I define it later in the same header file like this,

```
inline void swap(myClass &a, myClass &b)
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(a.i, b.i);
}
```

everything is fine. But if I **remove** the `inline` specifier, I get an error.

Now say I want to define `swap` in a separate implementation file instead. If I define it like this,

```
// impl.cc
#include "header.h"
void swap(myClass &a, myClass &b)
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(a.i, b.i);
}
```

everything is fine. But now if I **add** the `inline` specifier, I get an error.

Why does one version need `inline` but the other version can't have it?

Comment: Functions defined in header files should be inline (either explicitly or implicitly). Otherwise you get multiple definition errors when including the header file in more than one place. Conversely function defined in source files should not be inline otherwise if you want to use them outside of the source file they are defined in. That's about it really.

Comment: It's not usually a compilation problem though, unless the function is defined more than once in a single compilation unit (e.g. due to a header being included multiple times without include guards).    If multiple compilation units each have a definition, the practical result is often a linker error (multiply defined symbols or similar) not a compilation error (at least, with a compiler and linker based toolchain)

Comment: Twice you say "I get an error". Did it not occur to you to tell us the error messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the C++ Standard (9.1.6 The inline specifier)

> 6 **If an inline function or variable is odr-used in a translation unit,
>   a definition of it shall be reachable from the end of that translation
>   unit, and it shall have exactly the same definition in every such
>   translation unit (6.2).** [Note: A call to the inline function or a use
>   of the inline variable may be encountered before its definition
>   appears in the translation unit. —end note] If a definition of a
>   function or variable is reachable at the point of its first
>   declaration as inline, the program is ill-formed. If a function or
>   variable with external or module linkage is declared inline in one
>   translation unit, there shall be a reachable inline declaration in all
>   translation units in which it is declared; no diagnostic is required.
>   An inline function or variable with external or module linkage shall
>   have the same address in all translation units. [Note: A static local
>   variable in an inline function with external or module linkage always
>   refers to the same object. A type defined within the body of an inline
>   function with external or module linkage is the same type in every
>   translation unit. —end note]

So either you declare the friend function as an inline function in a header such a way that its definition is reachable in each translation unit where it is used. Or the function is a non-inline function and its definition shall be placed in one compilation unit to satisfy the One Definition Rule.